# My robot falls through the ground in gazebo world

Tags: python, ubuntu, ros, gazebo-simu, urdf

https://github.com/osrf/vrx

I am using the usv urdf file I created to open the gazevo world in the example link above. It seems to be able to load the model into the gazebo world, but there is a problem that the model continues to sink to the bottom. i want to know the solution for this

my urdf code is here:
`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="1kw" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro" >
    <xacro:include filename="$(find wamv_gazebo)/urdf/1kw2.gazebo.xacro"/>
    <xacro:include filename="$(find wamv_gazebo)/urdf/dynamics/wamv_gazebo_dynamics_plugin.xacro" />

    <!-- Define robot constants -->
    <xacro:property name="base_W" value="1.5"/>
    <xacro:property name="base_D" value="0.09"/>
    <xacro:property name="base_H" value="0.03"/>
    <xacro:property name="base_M" value="0.08"/>
    
    <xacro:macro name="base_inertia" params="m w d h">
        <inertial>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />      
            <mass value="${m}"/>
            <inertia ixx="${(m/12) * (d*d)}" ixy = "0" ixz = "0" iyy="${(m/12) * (w*w + d*d)}" iyz = "0" izz="${(m/12) * (w*w)}"/> 
        </inertial>
    </xacro:macro>

    <!-- Robot Footprint -->
    <link name="base_footprint"/>

    <joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_footprint"/>
        <child link="base_link"/>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.3" rpy="1.570796 0 0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <!-- USV Base -->
    <link name="base_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://oneusv_urdf/mesh/1kw_ship_body2.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.24 0 0.3"/>
            <material name="yellow">
                <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://oneusv_urdf/mesh/1kw_ship_body2.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.24 0 0.3"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="1"/>
            <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1" iyz="0.0" izz="1"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    
    <!-- IMU -->
    <joint name="imu_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="imu_link"/>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0 0.0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="imu_link"/>
    
    <joint name="lid_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="lid_link"/>
        <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <!-- USV lid -->
    <link name="lid_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://oneusv_urdf/mesh/1kw_ship_Lid.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.24 0 0.3"/>
            <material name="yellow">
                <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://oneusv_urdf/mesh/1kw_ship_Lid.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.24 0 0.3"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="1"/>
            <inertia ixx="10" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="10" iyz="0.0" izz="10"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    
    <joint name="lidar_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="lid_link"/>
        <child link="lidar_link"/>
        <origin xyz="0 0.235 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <!-- USV lidar -->
    <link name="lidar_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://oneusv_urdf/mesh/1kw_ship_Lidar.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.24 -0.235 0.3"/>
            <material name="yellow">
                <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://oneusv_urdf/mesh/1kw_ship_Lidar.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.24 -0.235 0.3"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="1"/>
            <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1" iyz="0.0" izz="1"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    
    <joint name="left_propeller_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="left_propeller_link"/>
        <origin xyz="0.6 -0.375 0.298" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <axis rpy="0 0 0" xyz="1 0 0"/>
        <limit effort="100" velocity="100" />
        <dynamics friction="0.05" damping="0.05" />
    </joint>
    
    <!-- USV left propeller -->
    <link name="left_propeller_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://oneusv_urdf/mesh/1kw_ship_left_propeller.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.84 0.375 0.002"/>
            <material name="yellow">
                <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://oneusv_urdf/mesh/1kw_ship_left_propeller.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.84 0.375 0.002"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="1"/>
            <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1" iyz="0.0" izz="1"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>

    <joint name="right_propeller_joint" type="continuous">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="right_propeller_link"/>
        <origin xyz="0.6 -0.375 -0.298" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <axis rpy="0 0 0" xyz="1 0 0"/>
        <limit effort="100" velocity="100" />
        <dynamics friction="0.05" damping="0.05" />
    </joint>
    
    <!-- USV right propeller -->
    <link name="right_propeller_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://oneusv_urdf/mesh/1kw_ship_right_propeller.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.84 0.375 0.598"/>
            <material name="yellow">
                <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://oneusv_urdf/mesh/1kw_ship_right_propeller.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.84 0.375 0.598"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="1"/>
            <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1" iyz="0.0" izz="1"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    
    <joint name="front_antenna_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="front_antenna_link"/>
        <origin xyz="-0.7898 0.05 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <!-- USV front antenna -->
    <link name="front_antenna_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://oneusv_urdf/mesh/1kw_ship_antenna_front.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.5498 -0.05 0.3"/>
            <material name="yellow">
                <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://oneusv_urdf/mesh/1kw_ship_antenna_front.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0.5498 -0.05 0.3"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="1"/>
            <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1" iyz="0.0" izz="1"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    
    <joint name="back_antenna_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="back_antenna_link"/>
        <origin xyz="0.7328 0.05 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <!-- USV back antenna -->
    <link name="back_antenna_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://oneusv_urdf/mesh/1kw_ship_antenna_back.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.9728 -0.05 0.3"/>
            <material name="yellow">
                <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://oneusv_urdf/mesh/1kw_ship_antenna_back.stl" scale="0.001 0.001 0.001"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="-0.9728 -0.05 0.3"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="1"/>
            <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1" iyz="0.0" izz="1"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    
    <joint name="left_cam_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="left_cam_link"/>
        <origin xyz="-0.812 -0.008 0.05" rpy="0 1.570796 0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <!-- USV left cam -->
    <link name="left_cam_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.02" radius="0.01"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <material name="yellow">
                <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.02" radius="0.01"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="1"/>
            <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1" iyz="0.0" izz="1"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    
    <joint name="right_cam_joint" type="fixed">
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="right_cam_link"/>
        <origin xyz="-0.812 -0.008 -0.05" rpy="0 1.570796 0"/>
    </joint>
    
    <!-- USV right cam -->
    <link name="right_cam_link">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.02" radius="0.01"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <material name="yellow">
                <color rgba="1 1 0 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>

        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <cylinder length="0.02" radius="0.01"/>
            </geometry>
            <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0"/>
        </collision>

        <inertial>
            <mass value="1"/>
            <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="1" iyz="0.0" izz="1"/>
        </inertial>
    </link>
    
</robot>
```

`

and my gazebo xacro code is here
`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot name="1kw" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro" >
    <xacro:arg name="laser_visual" default="false"/>
    <xacro:arg name="imu_visual"   default="false"/>

    <gazebo reference="base_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Gray</material>
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo reference="lid_link">
        <material>Gazebo/White</material>
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo reference="front_antenna_link">
        <material>Gazebo/White</material>
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo reference="back_antenna_link">
        <material>Gazebo/White</material>
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo reference="left_cam_link">
        <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
            <sensor type="camera" name="left_sensor">
            <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
        <visualize>false</visualize>
            <camera name="left_camera">
                <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
                <image>
                    <width>1280</width>
                    <height>720</height>
                    <format>R8G8B8</format>
                </image>
                <clip>
                    <near>0.05</near>
                    <far>300</far>
                </clip>
                <noise>
                    <type>gaussian</type>
                    <!-- Noise is sampled independently per pixel on each frame.
                         That pixel's noise value is added to each of its color
                          channels, which at that point lie in the range [0,1]. -->
                    <mean>0.0</mean>
                    <stddev>0.007</stddev>
                </noise>
            </camera>
            <plugin name="camera_plugin_left" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
                <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
                <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
                <cameraName>left_camera</cameraName>
                <imageTopicName>image_raw_left</imageTopicName>
                <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
                <frameName>left_cam_link</frameName>
                <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
                <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
                <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
                <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
                <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
                <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
            </plugin>
            </sensor>
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo reference="right_cam_link">
        <material>Gazebo/FlatBlack</material>
            <sensor type="camera" name="right_sensor">
            <update_rate>30.0</update_rate>
        <visualize>false</visualize>
            <camera name="right_camera">
                <horizontal_fov>1.3962634</horizontal_fov>
                <image>
                    <width>1280</width>
                    <height>720</height>
                    <format>R8G8B8</format>
                </image>
                <clip>
                    <near>0.05</near>
                    <far>300</far>
                </clip>
                <noise>
                    <type>gaussian</type>
                    <!-- Noise is sampled independently per pixel on each frame.
                         That pixel's noise value is added to each of its color
                          channels, which at that point lie in the range [0,1]. -->
                    <mean>0.0</mean>
                    <stddev>0.007</stddev>
                </noise>
            </camera>
            <plugin name="camera_plugin_right" filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so">
                <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
                <updateRate>0.0</updateRate>
                <cameraName>right_camera</cameraName>
                <imageTopicName>image_raw_right</imageTopicName>
                <cameraInfoTopicName>camera_info</cameraInfoTopicName>
                <frameName>right_cam_link</frameName>
                <hackBaseline>0.07</hackBaseline>
                <distortionK1>0.0</distortionK1>
                <distortionK2>0.0</distortionK2>
                <distortionK3>0.0</distortionK3>
                <distortionT1>0.0</distortionT1>
                <distortionT2>0.0</distortionT2>
            </plugin>
            </sensor> 
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo reference="imu_link">
        <sensor type="imu" name="imu">
            <always_on>true</always_on>
            <visualize>$(arg imu_visual)</visualize>
        </sensor>
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="imu_plugin" filename="libgazebo_ros_imu.so">
            <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            <bodyName>imu_link</bodyName>
            <frameName>imu_link</frameName>
            <topicName>imu</topicName>
            <serviceName>imu_service</serviceName>
            <gaussianNoise>0.0</gaussianNoise>
            <updateRate>0</updateRate>
            <imu>
                <noise>
                    <type>gaussian</type>
                    <rate>
                        <mean>0.0</mean>
                        <stddev>2e-4</stddev>
                        <bias_mean>0.0000075</bias_mean>
                        <bias_stddev>0.0000008</bias_stddev>
                    </rate>
                    <accel>
                        <mean>0.0</mean>
                        <stddev>1.7e-2</stddev>
                        <bias_mean>0.1</bias_mean>
                        <bias_stddev>0.001</bias_stddev>
                    </accel>
                </noise>
            </imu>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo reference="lidar_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo reference="left_propeller_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Gray</material>
            <mu1>0.1</mu1>
            <mu2>0.1</mu2>
            <kp>500000.0</kp>
            <kd>10.0</kd>
            <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
            <maxVel>0.1</maxVel>
            <fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo reference="right_propeller_link">
        <material>Gazebo/Gray</material> 
            <mu1>0.1</mu1>
            <mu2>0.1</mu2>
            <kp>500000.0</kp>
            <kd>10.0</kd>
            <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
            <maxVel>0.1</maxVel>
            <fdir1>1 0 0</fdir1>
    </gazebo>
    
    <gazebo>
        <plugin name="differential_drive_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_diff_drive.so">
            <commandTopic>cmd_vel</commandTopic>
            <odometryTopic>odom</odometryTopic>
            <odometryFrame>odom</odometryFrame>
            <odometrySource>world</odometrySource>
            <publishOdomTF>true</publishOdomTF>
            <robotBaseFrame>base_footprint</robotBaseFrame>
            <publishWheelTF>false</publishWheelTF>
            <publishTf>true</publishTf>
            <publishWheelJointState>true</publishWheelJointState>
            <legacyMode>false</legacyMode>
            <updateRate>30</updateRate>
            <leftJoint>left_propeller_joint</leftJoint>
            <rightJoint>right_propeller_joint</rightJoint>
            <wheelSeparation>0.596</wheelSeparation>
            <wheelDiameter>0.098</wheelDiameter>
            <wheelAcceleration>1</wheelAcceleration>
            <wheelTorque>10</wheelTorque>
            <rosDebugLevel>na</rosDebugLevel>
        </plugin>
    </gazebo>
    
</robot>
```

`

Comment: Just a random guess, you could try spawning robot higher above ground like 1m or even 5m

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues with this. I had to include a model of a ground plane in gazebo. The ground plane model will be static and act as a floor so your robots will continuously fall on this flat ground instead of through it.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34442982)